# How to fetch all Tokens that are present in a user's wallet with all the details like mint, amount and metadata of the mint?

Tags: solana-program, spl-token-program

I would like to get all the Token's that are present in the wallet address of a user with its balance, mint address, and the metadata of the Token. What's the Ideal way of doing it

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Here's a good start: [getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner](https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#how-to-get-all-token-accounts-by-owner)

Comment: Ya but it get's the NFT accounts as well. I know we can do filtering and stuff but man that's alot of rpc calls to make + alot of account deserilization happening